# What is the term for "cousin of a cousin"?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

My mother’s sister’s son is my cousin; let’s call him “John”.

John’s father’s brother’s son — let’s call him Mark — is John’s cousin.

Now, Mark isn’t my direct cousin as we don't share any immediate ancestors. What kind of relationship do I have with Mark? I think this too is some sort of cousin.

I always thought this was second cousin, but it turns out, I have blood relation to a second cousin through great grandparents.

So, what is term for my relationship with Mark?

Comment: You don't have one.

Comment: To pervert an old saying, "The cousin of my cousin is my cousin."

Comment: Since there is a marriage in there (John's parents) ... maybe we could invent a term and call that guy your *cousin-in-law*.

Comment: Someone gotta make up a term for cousin of my cousin. How about lets make up a slang term. Unrelational cousin?

Comment: I propose a new term: co-cousin. You jointly share a common cousin.

Comment: I like @GEdgar's suggestion the best. Shakespeare's generic term has also application for simplicity :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any *family relationship* between you and Mark, except

- the cousin of your cousin is *yourself* or your *sibling*
- the cousin of your cousin is also your *cousin* if his mother is the sister of your father
- the cousin of your cousin is your *second cousin* if his parents and your parents are cousins (*third cousin* if the parents are second cousins, and so on)

A term what many people use is *grand-cousin*. But that's wrong, though it is used ambiguous in colloquial, at least in my mother-tongue. But think of that:

- Your grandparents are the parents of your parent
- Your grandaunt/granduncle is the the aunt/uncle of your parent

This leads to

- Your grand-cousin is the cousin of your parent.

If no blood relation exists there are only few ways how a non-related person can be your cousin: E.g. the person is your step-cousin. But this doesn't work here, because:

> Step-cousins are either stepchildren of an individual's aunt or uncle, children of one's step-aunt or uncle, or half-siblings of one's cousin. <sup>([WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Step-cousins))</sup>

On the WP page you find a lot of family combinations and what they are called (e.g. *Cousin-in-law*: spouse of an individual's cousin), but I didn't find the relationship you mention. (Correct me, if I overlooked it)

Conclusion: I would call him *cousin of cousin*.

Comment: Maybe *grandcousin*?  :-)

Answer (score 5):

As you state, there is no common ancestor, so you are not related.

Colloquially, you can be "cousins" if there is a unique tie, and most readers would understand this. Technically, however, there is no relation.

The technical terms are as follows:

- Siblings share the same parents.
- Cousins share the same grandparents.
- Second cousins share the same great-grandparents.
- Third cousins share the same great-great-grandparents,

And so on.

The direct descendants of any cousin are "cousins once removed." thus, the direct child of your second cousins are second cousins once removed.". The grand children of your second cousins is your "second cousins twice removed." and so on.

In-laws refer to relatives related by marriage. As such, I might be tempted to force the construction "cousins-in-law", but it would be a stretch.

Comment: The grandchild of a second cousin is a second cousin once removed *of the other cousin*.  Children of second cousins are third cousins to each other.  "Once removed" (etc) is for cases where you're not at the same level in the tree.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a word which uniquely identifies that particular and no other relationship, there isn't one. But there is a perfectly good word which applies to such a relationship: *cousin*.

*Cousin* is used, not just for a particular technical degree of blood relation, but also for "someone who is related to you through a brother, sister, uncle, or aunt of one of your parents".[¹](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cousin)

The broad meaning of *cousin* has been in use since Shakespeare's time. In fact, Shakespeare used it for "virtually any relative beyond the immediate family, both for blood relatives and relatives through marriage, and often as a term of affection between socially equal people who are not relatives at all, such as monarchs of different countries".[²](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/cousin)

Comment: While I love this answer, I would like to point out that most European monarchs were, and still are, blood relatives. Even the ones that married each other, it's a whole thing.

Comment: Specifically, the kings of France and England got into a little spat you may know as the Hundred Years' War precisely because they were blood relatives, and inheritance laws weren't clear enough about who got which crown

Answer (score 0):

I have adpoted the term grand-cousin to mean the eldest cousin of your parent.

So, for example, Eric's mother is Kristine.  Kristine's eldest cousin is me.  So, I call myself grand-cousin.

Technically I am just one of Eric's 1st cousins once removed but being the eldest seemed special enough so I created the term grand-cousin before researching it.  Now I am researching it and came across this posting.

Comment: *Grand-cousin* has possibly existed *before* you 'adopted' it. You seem to have adopted it *before* you researched it.